# Toshiba Laptop reboots on battery

Tags: battery, toshiba-laptop, windows-server-2012

I recently had an almost dead battery on my Toshiba laptop and bought a new one on ebay.  The moment I installed the battery, my system staretd behaving differently, it just went dead after a few minutes, I thought it was the bad battery and sent it back to the seller, howevver after this incident even on the old battery it started misbehaving. The system keeps giving me "The display adapter failed and recovered".

My configurations are

1. Its a Toshiba Laptop with an i7 processor (forgot the laptop model number)
2. I run Windows Server 2012
3. This machine uses an AMD Radeon 7500 Graphics

The system runs perfectly for even 12-18 hours if its on AC supply and it works fine for upto 10 minutes even on battery, but after 10 minutes it goes out.

My question is, how can I find which part is causing the issue, how can I go about debugging this.

Note: The battery seller shipped me a new battery on complaining and the situation has not improved even after using that.

Comment: Did you check if the battery's amperage and voltage matches the laptop's before plugging it in?

Comment: @Alex can you tell me how I can check this, right now the system went off and without powering the laptop on I am on this again so it doesnt look to be battery side issue at least to do with capacity

Comment: The specs are written on the battery, and on the laptop (in the battery slot)